How do I schedule a one-time alarm for a specific day?
I want to set a one-time alarm to go off on a specific date on my iPhone. On Android there was a "Schedule alarm" button in the clock app but I can't find an equivalent option on iOS. The reminders app doesn't work for this because I want the alarm to keep going off until I wake up and disable it. I'm willing to purchase a third party app to accomplish this.
How do I schedule a one-time alarm for a specific day in iOS?

Scheduling an alarm on Android

Why does a scheduled event with an alarm not work in your case?

@nohillside How do you make a scheduled event with an alarm?

Like any other, and set an alert.

Use the Calendar: create an event, and set an alarm for it.

@benwiggy I see an alert option in the calendar app, but that only sends a single notification. I'm looking for an alarm that will keep going off until I turn it off.

iOS timers can be longer than 24 hours, and share behaviours with alarms like triggering until silenced.
I made a shortcut Create a timer which prompts for a date and time, calculates minutes until then, and creates a timer for that duration.

On devices with a Dynamic Island, live activities show on it, including this timer. To hide a live activity, collapse by swiping towards the center.

Great shortcut. Is there any way to hide the timer that appears in the dynamic island with this method?

@Stevoisiak Added the best solution I know, collapsing the live activity, to the answer.

The app Alarm & Timer allows specifying a specific date for alarms.

Open Alarm & Timer
Go to the Alarm tab
Click the + button to create an alarm
Specify the time you want
Click the calendar icon in the top left
Select a date and hit ok
Save alarm

By default the alarm will keep playing until you manually interact with your phone. Note that the alarm will not play sound if your phone is set to Silent.

